# how to convert a split Appledouble font to a cross-platform font type

Tags: windows, macos, fonts, cygwin, file-conversion

so, we have a designer that used a fancy font family(Frutiger to be specific) and when we went to design the website for the client we had a problem, the designer forgot to send the font, so we mail back and they send a zip file. however the designer used a mac font on(surprise) a mac. we need a cross-platform font to include on the website.

upon opening the zip file our mac developers can see fonts, but not font files.
upon opening the zip file our windows devs see the following:

```
  - ._MACOSX
    + Frutiger
        * FrutiBla(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiBlaIta(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiBol(this is a file with size)
        * Frutiger(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiIta(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiLig(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiLigIta(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiRom(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiUtiBla(this is a file with size)
    + Frutiger Black
        * FrutiBla(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiBlaIta(this is a file with size)
        * Fruti Black(this is a file with size)
    + Frutiger Bold
        * FrutiBol(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiBolIta(this is a file with size)
    + Frutiger Condensed
        * FrutiBlaCn(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiBolCn(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiExtBlaCn(this is a file with size)
        * Frutiger Condensed(this is a file with size)
        * FrutiLigCn(this is a file with size)
    + Frutiger Italic
        * Frutiger Italic(this is a file with size)
        * FrutigerIta(this is a file with size)
  - Frutiger
    + FrutiBla(this is a file)
    + FrutiBlaIta(this is a file)
    + FrutiBol(this is a file)
    + Frutiger(this is a file)
    + FrutiIta(this is a file)
    + FrutiLig(this is a file)
    + FrutiLigIta(this is a file)
    + FrutiRom(this is a file)
    + FrutiUtiBla(this is a file)
  - Frutiger Black
    + FrutiBla(this is a file)
    + FrutiBlaIta(this is a file)
    + Fruti Black(this is a file)
  - Frutiger Bold
    + FrutiBol(this is a file)
    + FrutiBolIta(this is a file)
  - Frutiger Condensed
    + FrutiBlaCn(this is a file)
    + FrutiBolCn(this is a file)
    + FrutiExtBlaCn(this is a file)
    + Frutiger Condensed(this is a file)
    + FrutiLigCn(this is a file)
  - Frutiger Italic
    + Frutiger Italic(this is a file)
    + FrutigerIta(this is a file)
```

apon digging i unearthed a filetype identifier called TrIDNET which upon selecting any of these files would take it and tell me that it was a "Mac Appledouble encoded" type file:

[image: http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b501/kjc_igd/Capture_zps09ff80fc.png]

so i tried fontforge and it couldn't recognize it:

[image: http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b501/kjc_igd/Capture2_zpsb0eed013.png]

tried online converters. they only took one file at a time(which ends up being half the file i guess.

tried DFontSplitter but there was no .dfont files to work with, only the file hierarchy shown above

so i Installed Cygwin(talk about a buggy install) and downloaded the Fondu GnuZip file and extracted it in Cygwin and then used  ./configure on it

```
$ cd /fondu
$ ./configure
  checking for gcc... gcc
  checking for C compiler default output... a.exe
  checking whether the C compiler works... yes
  checking whether we are cross compiling... no
  checking for suffix of executables... .exe
  checking for suffix of object files... o
  checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
  checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
  checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
  checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
  configure: creating ./config.status
  config.status: creating Makefile
```

./config.status being the following unwieldy amount of code:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Generated by configure.
# Run this file to recreate the current configuration.
# Compiler output produced by configure, useful for debugging
# configure, is in config.log if it exists.

debug=false
SHELL=${CONFIG_SHELL-/bin/sh}

## --------------------- ##
## M4sh Initialization.  ##
## --------------------- ##

# Be Bourne compatible
if test -n "${ZSH_VERSION+set}" && (emulate sh) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  emulate sh
  NULLCMD=:
elif test -n "${BASH_VERSION+set}" && (set -o posix) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  set -o posix
fi

# NLS nuisances.
# Support unset when possible.
if (FOO=FOO; unset FOO) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  as_unset=unset
else
  as_unset=false
fi

(set +x; test -n "`(LANG=C; export LANG) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LANG || test "${LANG+set}" != set; } ||
      { LANG=C; export LANG; }
(set +x; test -n "`(LC_ALL=C; export LC_ALL) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LC_ALL || test "${LC_ALL+set}" != set; } ||
      { LC_ALL=C; export LC_ALL; }
(set +x; test -n "`(LC_TIME=C; export LC_TIME) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LC_TIME || test "${LC_TIME+set}" != set; } ||
      { LC_TIME=C; export LC_TIME; }
(set +x; test -n "`(LC_CTYPE=C; export LC_CTYPE) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LC_CTYPE || test "${LC_CTYPE+set}" != set; } ||
      { LC_CTYPE=C; export LC_CTYPE; }
(set +x; test -n "`(LANGUAGE=C; export LANGUAGE) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LANGUAGE || test "${LANGUAGE+set}" != set; } ||
      { LANGUAGE=C; export LANGUAGE; }
(set +x; test -n "`(LC_COLLATE=C; export LC_COLLATE) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LC_COLLATE || test "${LC_COLLATE+set}" != set; } ||
      { LC_COLLATE=C; export LC_COLLATE; }
(set +x; test -n "`(LC_NUMERIC=C; export LC_NUMERIC) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LC_NUMERIC || test "${LC_NUMERIC+set}" != set; } ||
      { LC_NUMERIC=C; export LC_NUMERIC; }
(set +x; test -n "`(LC_MESSAGES=C; export LC_MESSAGES) 2>&1`") &&
    { $as_unset LC_MESSAGES || test "${LC_MESSAGES+set}" != set; } ||
      { LC_MESSAGES=C; export LC_MESSAGES; }


# Name of the executable.
as_me=`(basename "$0") 2>/dev/null ||
$as_expr X/"$0" : '.*/\([^/][^/]*\)/*$' \| \
     X"$0" : 'X\(//\)$' \| \
     X"$0" : 'X\(/\)$' \| \
     .     : '\(.\)' 2>/dev/null ||
echo X/"$0" |
    sed '/^.*\/\([^/][^/]*\)\/*$/{ s//\1/; q; }
      /^X\/\(\/\/\)$/{ s//\1/; q; }
      /^X\/\(\/\).*/{ s//\1/; q; }
      s/.*/./; q'`

# PATH needs CR, and LINENO needs CR and PATH.
# Avoid depending upon Character Ranges.
as_cr_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
as_cr_LETTERS='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
as_cr_Letters=$as_cr_letters$as_cr_LETTERS
as_cr_digits='0123456789'
as_cr_alnum=$as_cr_Letters$as_cr_digits

# The user is always right.
if test "${PATH_SEPARATOR+set}" != set; then
  echo "#! /bin/sh" >conftest.sh
  echo  "exit 0"   >>conftest.sh
  chmod +x conftest.sh
  if (PATH=".;."; conftest.sh) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    PATH_SEPARATOR=';'
  else
    PATH_SEPARATOR=:
  fi
  rm -f conftest.sh
fi


  as_lineno_1=$LINENO
  as_lineno_2=$LINENO
  as_lineno_3=`(expr $as_lineno_1 + 1) 2>/dev/null`
  test "x$as_lineno_1" != "x$as_lineno_2" &&
  test "x$as_lineno_3"  = "x$as_lineno_2"  || {
  # Find who we are.  Look in the path if we contain no path at all
  # relative or not.
  case $0 in
    *[\\/]* ) as_myself=$0 ;;
    *) as_save_IFS=$IFS; IFS=$PATH_SEPARATOR
for as_dir in $PATH
do
  IFS=$as_save_IFS
  test -z "$as_dir" && as_dir=.
  test -r "$as_dir/$0" && as_myself=$as_dir/$0 && break
done

       ;;
  esac
  # We did not find ourselves, most probably we were run as `sh COMMAND'
  # in which case we are not to be found in the path.
  if test "x$as_myself" = x; then
    as_myself=$0
  fi
  if test ! -f "$as_myself"; then
    { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: cannot find myself; rerun with an absolute path" >&5
echo "$as_me: error: cannot find myself; rerun with an absolute path" >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }
  fi
  case $CONFIG_SHELL in
  '')
    as_save_IFS=$IFS; IFS=$PATH_SEPARATOR
for as_dir in /bin$PATH_SEPARATOR/usr/bin$PATH_SEPARATOR$PATH
do
  IFS=$as_save_IFS
  test -z "$as_dir" && as_dir=.
  for as_base in sh bash ksh sh5; do
     case $as_dir in
     /*)
       if ("$as_dir/$as_base" -c '
  as_lineno_1=$LINENO
  as_lineno_2=$LINENO
  as_lineno_3=`(expr $as_lineno_1 + 1) 2>/dev/null`
  test "x$as_lineno_1" != "x$as_lineno_2" &&
  test "x$as_lineno_3"  = "x$as_lineno_2" ') 2>/dev/null; then
         CONFIG_SHELL=$as_dir/$as_base
         export CONFIG_SHELL
         exec "$CONFIG_SHELL" "$0" ${1+"$@"}
       fi;;
     esac
       done
done
;;
  esac

  # Create $as_me.lineno as a copy of $as_myself, but with $LINENO
  # uniformly replaced by the line number.  The first 'sed' inserts a
  # line-number line before each line; the second 'sed' does the real
  # work.  The second script uses 'N' to pair each line-number line
  # with the numbered line, and appends trailing '-' during
  # substitution so that $LINENO is not a special case at line end.
  # (Raja R Harinath suggested sed '=', and Paul Eggert wrote the
  # second 'sed' script.  Blame Lee E. McMahon for sed's syntax.  :-)
  sed '=' <$as_myself |
    sed '
      N
      s,$,-,
      : loop
      s,^\(['$as_cr_digits']*\)\(.*\)[$]LINENO\([^'$as_cr_alnum'_]\),\1\2\1\3,
      t loop
      s,-$,,
      s,^['$as_cr_digits']*\n,,
    ' >$as_me.lineno &&
  chmod +x $as_me.lineno ||
    { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: cannot create $as_me.lineno; rerun with a POSIX shell" >&5
echo "$as_me: error: cannot create $as_me.lineno; rerun with a POSIX shell" >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }

  # Don't try to exec as it changes $[0], causing all sort of problems
  # (the dirname of $[0] is not the place where we might find the
  # original and so on.  Autoconf is especially sensible to this).
  . ./$as_me.lineno
  # Exit status is that of the last command.
  exit
}


case `echo "testing\c"; echo 1,2,3`,`echo -n testing; echo 1,2,3` in
  *c*,-n*) ECHO_N= ECHO_C='
' ECHO_T='  ' ;;
  *c*,*  ) ECHO_N=-n ECHO_C= ECHO_T= ;;
  *)       ECHO_N= ECHO_C='\c' ECHO_T= ;;
esac

if expr a : '\(a\)' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  as_expr=expr
else
  as_expr=false
fi

rm -f conf$$ conf$$.exe conf$$.file
echo >conf$$.file
if ln -s conf$$.file conf$$ 2>/dev/null; then
  # We could just check for DJGPP; but this test a) works b) is more generic
  # and c) will remain valid once DJGPP supports symlinks (DJGPP 2.04).
  if test -f conf$$.exe; then
    # Don't use ln at all; we don't have any links
    as_ln_s='cp -p'
  else
    as_ln_s='ln -s'
  fi
elif ln conf$$.file conf$$ 2>/dev/null; then
  as_ln_s=ln
else
  as_ln_s='cp -p'
fi
rm -f conf$$ conf$$.exe conf$$.file

as_executable_p="test -f"

# Sed expression to map a string onto a valid CPP name.
as_tr_cpp="sed y%*$as_cr_letters%P$as_cr_LETTERS%;s%[^_$as_cr_alnum]%_%g"

# Sed expression to map a string onto a valid variable name.
as_tr_sh="sed y%*+%pp%;s%[^_$as_cr_alnum]%_%g"


# IFS
# We need space, tab and new line, in precisely that order.
as_nl='
'
IFS="   $as_nl"

# CDPATH.
$as_unset CDPATH || test "${CDPATH+set}" != set || { CDPATH=$PATH_SEPARATOR; export CDPATH; }

exec 6>&1

# Open the log real soon, to keep \$[0] and so on meaningful, and to
# report actual input values of CONFIG_FILES etc. instead of their
# values after options handling.  Logging --version etc. is OK.
exec 5>>config.log
{
  echo
  sed 'h;s/./-/g;s/^.../## /;s/...$/ ##/;p;x;p;x' <<_ASBOX
## Running $as_me. ##
_ASBOX
} >&5
cat >&5 <<_CSEOF

This file was extended by $as_me, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.53.  Invocation command line was

  CONFIG_FILES    = $CONFIG_FILES
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = $CONFIG_HEADERS
  CONFIG_LINKS    = $CONFIG_LINKS
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = $CONFIG_COMMANDS
  $ $0 $@

_CSEOF
echo "on `(hostname || uname -n) 2>/dev/null | sed 1q`" >&5
echo >&5
config_files=" Makefile"

ac_cs_usage="\
\`$as_me' instantiates files from templates according to the
current configuration.

Usage: $0 [OPTIONS] [FILE]...

  -h, --help       print this help, then exit
  -V, --version    print version number, then exit
  -d, --debug      don't remove temporary files
      --recheck    update $as_me by reconfiguring in the same conditions
  --file=FILE[:TEMPLATE]
                   instantiate the configuration file FILE

Configuration files:
$config_files

Report bugs to <bug-autoconf@gnu.org>."
ac_cs_version="\
config.status
configured by ./configure, generated by GNU Autoconf 2.53,
  with options \"\"

Copyright 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001
Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This config.status script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it."
srcdir=.
# If no file are specified by the user, then we need to provide default
# value.  By we need to know if files were specified by the user.
ac_need_defaults=:
while test $# != 0
do
  case $1 in
  --*=*)
    ac_option=`expr "x$1" : 'x\([^=]*\)='`
    ac_optarg=`expr "x$1" : 'x[^=]*=\(.*\)'`
    shift
    set dummy "$ac_option" "$ac_optarg" ${1+"$@"}
    shift
    ;;
  -*);;
  *) # This is not an option, so the user has probably given explicit
     # arguments.
     ac_need_defaults=false;;
  esac

  case $1 in
  # Handling of the options.
  -recheck | --recheck | --rechec | --reche | --rech | --rec | --re | --r)
    echo "running /bin/sh ./configure "  " --no-create --no-recursion"
    exec /bin/sh ./configure  --no-create --no-recursion ;;
  --version | --vers* | -V )
    echo "$ac_cs_version"; exit 0 ;;
  --he | --h)
    # Conflict between --help and --header
    { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: ambiguous option: $1
Try \`$0 --help' for more information." >&5
echo "$as_me: error: ambiguous option: $1
Try \`$0 --help' for more information." >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; };;
  --help | --hel | -h )
    echo "$ac_cs_usage"; exit 0 ;;
  --debug | --d* | -d )
    debug=: ;;
  --file | --fil | --fi | --f )
    shift
    CONFIG_FILES="$CONFIG_FILES $1"
    ac_need_defaults=false;;
  --header | --heade | --head | --hea )
    shift
    CONFIG_HEADERS="$CONFIG_HEADERS $1"
    ac_need_defaults=false;;

  # This is an error.
  -*) { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: unrecognized option: $1
Try \`$0 --help' for more information." >&5
echo "$as_me: error: unrecognized option: $1
Try \`$0 --help' for more information." >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; } ;;

  *) ac_config_targets="$ac_config_targets $1" ;;

  esac
  shift
done

for ac_config_target in $ac_config_targets
do
  case "$ac_config_target" in
  # Handling of arguments.
  "Makefile" ) CONFIG_FILES="$CONFIG_FILES Makefile" ;;
  *) { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: invalid argument: $ac_config_target" >&5
echo "$as_me: error: invalid argument: $ac_config_target" >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; };;
  esac
done

# If the user did not use the arguments to specify the items to instantiate,
# then the envvar interface is used.  Set only those that are not.
# We use the long form for the default assignment because of an extremely
# bizarre bug on SunOS 4.1.3.
if $ac_need_defaults; then
  test "${CONFIG_FILES+set}" = set || CONFIG_FILES=$config_files
fi

# Create a temporary directory, and hook for its removal unless debugging.
$debug ||
{
  trap 'exit_status=$?; rm -rf $tmp && exit $exit_status' 0
  trap '{ (exit 1); exit 1; }' 1 2 13 15
}

# Create a (secure) tmp directory for tmp files.
: ${TMPDIR=/tmp}
{
  tmp=`(umask 077 && mktemp -d -q "$TMPDIR/csXXXXXX") 2>/dev/null` &&
  test -n "$tmp" && test -d "$tmp"
}  ||
{
  tmp=$TMPDIR/cs$$-$RANDOM
  (umask 077 && mkdir $tmp)
} ||
{
   echo "$me: cannot create a temporary directory in $TMPDIR" >&2
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }
}


#
# CONFIG_FILES section.
#

# No need to generate the scripts if there are no CONFIG_FILES.
# This happens for instance when ./config.status config.h
if test -n "$CONFIG_FILES"; then
  # Protect against being on the right side of a sed subst in config.status.
  sed 's/,@/@@/; s/@,/@@/; s/,;t t$/@;t t/; /@;t t$/s/[\\&,]/\\&/g;
   s/@@/,@/; s/@@/@,/; s/@;t t$/,;t t/' >$tmp/subs.sed <<\CEOF
s,@SHELL@,/bin/sh,;t t
s,@PATH_SEPARATOR@,:,;t t
s,@PACKAGE_NAME@,,;t t
s,@PACKAGE_TARNAME@,,;t t
s,@PACKAGE_VERSION@,,;t t
s,@PACKAGE_STRING@,,;t t
s,@PACKAGE_BUGREPORT@,,;t t
s,@exec_prefix@,${prefix},;t t
s,@prefix@,/usr/local,;t t
s,@program_transform_name@,s,x,x,,;t t
s,@bindir@,${exec_prefix}/bin,;t t
s,@sbindir@,${exec_prefix}/sbin,;t t
s,@libexecdir@,${exec_prefix}/libexec,;t t
s,@datadir@,${prefix}/share,;t t
s,@sysconfdir@,${prefix}/etc,;t t
s,@sharedstatedir@,${prefix}/com,;t t
s,@localstatedir@,${prefix}/var,;t t
s,@libdir@,${exec_prefix}/lib,;t t
s,@includedir@,${prefix}/include,;t t
s,@oldincludedir@,/usr/include,;t t
s,@infodir@,${prefix}/info,;t t
s,@mandir@,${prefix}/man,;t t
s,@build_alias@,,;t t
s,@host_alias@,,;t t
s,@target_alias@,,;t t
s,@DEFS@,-DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" ,;t t
s,@ECHO_C@,,;t t
s,@ECHO_N@,-n,;t t
s,@ECHO_T@,,;t t
s,@LIBS@,,;t t
s,@CC@,gcc,;t t
s,@CFLAGS@,-g -O2,;t t
s,@LDFLAGS@,,;t t
s,@CPPFLAGS@,,;t t
s,@ac_ct_CC@,gcc,;t t
s,@EXEEXT@,.exe,;t t
s,@OBJEXT@,o,;t t
s,@build@,i686-pc-cygwin,;t t
s,@build_cpu@,i686,;t t
s,@build_vendor@,pc,;t t
s,@build_os@,cygwin,;t t
s,@host@,i686-pc-cygwin,;t t
s,@host_cpu@,i686,;t t
s,@host_vendor@,pc,;t t
s,@host_os@,cygwin,;t t
CEOF

  # Split the substitutions into bite-sized pieces for seds with
  # small command number limits, like on Digital OSF/1 and HP-UX.
  ac_max_sed_lines=48
  ac_sed_frag=1 # Number of current file.
  ac_beg=1 # First line for current file.
  ac_end=$ac_max_sed_lines # Line after last line for current file.
  ac_more_lines=:
  ac_sed_cmds=
  while $ac_more_lines; do
    if test $ac_beg -gt 1; then
      sed "1,${ac_beg}d; ${ac_end}q" $tmp/subs.sed >$tmp/subs.frag
    else
      sed "${ac_end}q" $tmp/subs.sed >$tmp/subs.frag
    fi
    if test ! -s $tmp/subs.frag; then
      ac_more_lines=false
    else
      # The purpose of the label and of the branching condition is to
      # speed up the sed processing (if there are no `@' at all, there
      # is no need to browse any of the substitutions).
      # These are the two extra sed commands mentioned above.
      (echo ':t
  /@[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*@/!b' && cat $tmp/subs.frag) >$tmp/subs-$ac_sed_frag.sed
      if test -z "$ac_sed_cmds"; then
    ac_sed_cmds="sed -f $tmp/subs-$ac_sed_frag.sed"
      else
    ac_sed_cmds="$ac_sed_cmds | sed -f $tmp/subs-$ac_sed_frag.sed"
      fi
      ac_sed_frag=`expr $ac_sed_frag + 1`
      ac_beg=$ac_end
      ac_end=`expr $ac_end + $ac_max_sed_lines`
    fi
  done
  if test -z "$ac_sed_cmds"; then
    ac_sed_cmds=cat
  fi
fi # test -n "$CONFIG_FILES"

for ac_file in : $CONFIG_FILES; do test "x$ac_file" = x: && continue
  # Support "outfile[:infile[:infile...]]", defaulting infile="outfile.in".
  case $ac_file in
  - | *:- | *:-:* ) # input from stdin
        cat >$tmp/stdin
        ac_file_in=`echo "$ac_file" | sed 's,[^:]*:,,'`
        ac_file=`echo "$ac_file" | sed 's,:.*,,'` ;;
  *:* ) ac_file_in=`echo "$ac_file" | sed 's,[^:]*:,,'`
        ac_file=`echo "$ac_file" | sed 's,:.*,,'` ;;
  * )   ac_file_in=$ac_file.in ;;
  esac

  # Compute @srcdir@, @top_srcdir@, and @INSTALL@ for subdirectories.
  ac_dir=`(dirname "$ac_file") 2>/dev/null ||
$as_expr X"$ac_file" : 'X\(.*[^/]\)//*[^/][^/]*/*$' \| \
         X"$ac_file" : 'X\(//\)[^/]' \| \
         X"$ac_file" : 'X\(//\)$' \| \
         X"$ac_file" : 'X\(/\)' \| \
         .     : '\(.\)' 2>/dev/null ||
echo X"$ac_file" |
    sed '/^X\(.*[^/]\)\/\/*[^/][^/]*\/*$/{ s//\1/; q; }
      /^X\(\/\/\)[^/].*/{ s//\1/; q; }
      /^X\(\/\/\)$/{ s//\1/; q; }
      /^X\(\/\).*/{ s//\1/; q; }
      s/.*/./; q'`
  { case "$ac_dir" in
  [\\/]* | ?:[\\/]* ) as_incr_dir=;;
  *)                      as_incr_dir=.;;
esac
as_dummy="$ac_dir"
for as_mkdir_dir in `IFS='/\\'; set X $as_dummy; shift; echo "$@"`; do
  case $as_mkdir_dir in
    # Skip DOS drivespec
    ?:) as_incr_dir=$as_mkdir_dir ;;
    *)
      as_incr_dir=$as_incr_dir/$as_mkdir_dir
      test -d "$as_incr_dir" ||
        mkdir "$as_incr_dir" ||
    { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: cannot create \"$ac_dir\"" >&5
echo "$as_me: error: cannot create \"$ac_dir\"" >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }
    ;;
  esac
done; }

  ac_builddir=.

if test "$ac_dir" != .; then
  ac_dir_suffix=/`echo "$ac_dir" | sed 's,^\.[\\/],,'`
  # A "../" for each directory in $ac_dir_suffix.
  ac_top_builddir=`echo "$ac_dir_suffix" | sed 's,/[^\\/]*,../,g'`
else
  ac_dir_suffix= ac_top_builddir=
fi

case $srcdir in
  .)  # No --srcdir option.  We are building in place.
    ac_srcdir=.
    if test -z "$ac_top_builddir"; then
       ac_top_srcdir=.
    else
       ac_top_srcdir=`echo $ac_top_builddir | sed 's,/$,,'`
    fi ;;
  [\\/]* | ?:[\\/]* )  # Absolute path.
    ac_srcdir=$srcdir$ac_dir_suffix;
    ac_top_srcdir=$srcdir ;;
  *) # Relative path.
    ac_srcdir=$ac_top_builddir$srcdir$ac_dir_suffix
    ac_top_srcdir=$ac_top_builddir$srcdir ;;
esac
# Don't blindly perform a `cd "$ac_dir"/$ac_foo && pwd` since $ac_foo can be
# absolute.
ac_abs_builddir=`cd "$ac_dir" && cd $ac_builddir && pwd`
ac_abs_top_builddir=`cd "$ac_dir" && cd $ac_top_builddir && pwd`
ac_abs_srcdir=`cd "$ac_dir" && cd $ac_srcdir && pwd`
ac_abs_top_srcdir=`cd "$ac_dir" && cd $ac_top_srcdir && pwd`



  if test x"$ac_file" != x-; then
    { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: creating $ac_file" >&5
echo "$as_me: creating $ac_file" >&6;}
    rm -f "$ac_file"
  fi
  # Let's still pretend it is `configure' which instantiates (i.e., don't
  # use $as_me), people would be surprised to read:
  #    /* config.h.  Generated by config.status.  */
  if test x"$ac_file" = x-; then
    configure_input=
  else
    configure_input="$ac_file.  "
  fi
  configure_input=$configure_input"Generated from `echo $ac_file_in |
                                     sed 's,.*/,,'` by configure."

  # First look for the input files in the build tree, otherwise in the
  # src tree.
  ac_file_inputs=`IFS=:
    for f in $ac_file_in; do
      case $f in
      -) echo $tmp/stdin ;;
      [\\/$]*)
         # Absolute (can't be DOS-style, as IFS=:)
         test -f "$f" || { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: cannot find input file: $f" >&5
echo "$as_me: error: cannot find input file: $f" >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }
         echo $f;;
      *) # Relative
         if test -f "$f"; then
           # Build tree
           echo $f
         elif test -f "$srcdir/$f"; then
           # Source tree
           echo $srcdir/$f
         else
           # /dev/null tree
           { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: cannot find input file: $f" >&5
echo "$as_me: error: cannot find input file: $f" >&2;}
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }
         fi;;
      esac
    done` || { (exit 1); exit 1; }
  sed "/^[  ]*VPATH[    ]*=/{
s/:*\$(srcdir):*/:/;
s/:*\${srcdir}:*/:/;
s/:*@srcdir@:*/:/;
s/^\([^=]*=[    ]*\):*/\1/;
s/:*$//;
s/^[^=]*=[  ]*$//;
}

:t
/@[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*@/!b
s,@configure_input@,$configure_input,;t t
s,@srcdir@,$ac_srcdir,;t t
s,@abs_srcdir@,$ac_abs_srcdir,;t t
s,@top_srcdir@,$ac_top_srcdir,;t t
s,@abs_top_srcdir@,$ac_abs_top_srcdir,;t t
s,@builddir@,$ac_builddir,;t t
s,@abs_builddir@,$ac_abs_builddir,;t t
s,@top_builddir@,$ac_top_builddir,;t t
s,@abs_top_builddir@,$ac_abs_top_builddir,;t t
" $ac_file_inputs | (eval "$ac_sed_cmds") >$tmp/out
  rm -f $tmp/stdin
  if test x"$ac_file" != x-; then
    mv $tmp/out $ac_file
  else
    cat $tmp/out
    rm -f $tmp/out
  fi

done

{ (exit 0); exit 0; }
```

and the log file:

http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b501/kjc_igd/code_zpsf6313db1.jpg

but i though okay it is installed! now i can finally convert the file, right? no.

```
$ fondu Frituger.dfont
bash: fondu: command not found
```

the thing won't even recognize the command.

so i need the following:
  A. better directions for fondu(because nobody seems to have them.)
  B. A fix for what i messed up in fondu(because i am not an expert on running these things)
  C. A different way to convert a mac file-tree into a universal font file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at are a combination of Mac font suitcase files and Mac PostScript Type 1 outline font files. Both of these types of files are resource-fork-based and contain file type and creator codes, which is why they need to be split into the 2 halves (`file`/`._file` or `file`/`__MACOSX/file`) halves to preserve all that information in the zip file.

When you unzip the .zip archive on a Mac, the 2 halves are joined together via the `/System/Library/CoreServices/FixupResourceForks` tool. Of course, this will only work on a file system that supports resource forks like HFS.

I'll try to describe the structure you're seeing when you look at the unzipped archive on a Windows machine. Inside the `Frutiger` folder, you have the following files:

```
Frutiger

FrutiBla
FrutiBlaIta
FrutiBol
FrutiIta
FrutiLig
FrutiLigIta
FrutiRom
FrutiUtiBla
```

The first file listed, `Frutiger`, is most likely the Mac font suitcase file. It can be named anything, and changing its name won't affect the usability of the font. This Mac font suitcase file will contain the `FOND` (font family information) and `NFNT` (bitmap font instances) for the font in question.

You'll notice that the filenames of the next 8 files follow the `5-3-3` naming convention used for Mac PostScript Type 1 fonts. What I mean is, to get the filenames of the PostScript fonts that the font suitcase references, you take the first 5 letters of the family name (`Fruti`) then append the first 3 letters of each style in the PostScript name. So, `Frutiger Black Italic` is `Fruti` + `Bla` + `Ita` == `FrutiBlaIta`. These last 8 files contain the PostScript Type 1 outline font data in the form of a `POST` resource in the resource fork.

You mentioned trying to use DFontSplitter, but these aren't Mac Font suitcases that represent a Mac TrueType font suitcase, as it's unlikely there are any `sfnt` resources in the `Frutiger` font suitcase file.

I'm not sure if it's possible, from Windows, to convert these files into usable fonts (PostScript Type 1 windows fonts I would assume). Looking over the documentation for `fondu`, it may be able to help you, provided you can convert the AppleDouble encoded files into a format that `fondu` understands: Macbinary (.bin), binhex (.hqx), or data-fork-based resource file (.dfont or no extension at all).

When you do use `fondu`, it looks like you'll want to pass the `-trackps` and `-afm` options. For example, if you were to do the folder above, you'd do something like this:

```
fondu -trackps -afm Frutiger
```

Note that the filename of `Frutiger` may differ depending on what format you converted the AppleDouble encoded original `Frutiger` to. Since you're performing that on the font suitcase file, which contains the `FOND` information, fondu should be able to "follow" the PostScript Type 1 font files referenced in the FOND, and convert each of the `5-3-3` files to a `.pfb` file. Since the `FOND` resource will also likely contain font kerning and metrics information, you'll be able have fondu extract that out into an `.afm` file (which you will need to use another tool to convert to `.pfm` for later versions of Windows).

Regarding the following error you're getting:

```
$ fondu Frituger.dfont
bash: fondu: command not found
```

That's not an error that `fondu` is reporting, that's an error that `bash` is reporting. `bash` is the shell you're running in, and it's saying that it can't find a command named `fondu` in all its known paths. If you're currently still in the build directory where the `fondu` executable is located, you should use a preceding `./` to tell `bash` you mean the `fondu` that is in the current directory, not a `fondu` command that is one of its known paths:

```
 $ ./fondu Frutiger.dfont
```